# Organize Symfony project for country domains

Tags: symfony1, targeting

I don't know how to make a multidomain project.
Project has domain for each country, like:

- www.domain.com (root, for choose country)
- www.domain.co.uk (for UK)
- www.domain.ru (for RU)

Data in website will dependen of current Country (domain).
I newbie in Symfony, but i realy like it.

I think i need use something in User class, like `$this->getUser()->setCulture('UK');`

Has Symfony some plugin, or native tools to make it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one the solutions stated on [how to Configure Symfony 1.4 project for multiple domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213148/how-to-configure-symfony-1-4-project-for-multiple-domains/13259459#13259459)

To get user current location, you could use an external service like [ip2location](http://www.ip2location.com/)

```
//requires ip2location class

try {
    $ip = new ip2location;
    $ip->open('./db/IP-COUNTRY.BIN');

    $country_code = $ip->getCountryShort($ip_address);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    // ...
}
```